# Relationship by array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have an author_id array. I want to fetch authors by IDs using relationship. I already fetched editions and publishers but the author has an array.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | title            | author_id      | edition_id | publisher_id |
|----|------------------|----------------|------------|--------------|
| 2  | Web Development  | ["1","3","4"]  | 2          | 1            |
|----|------------------|----------------|------------|--------------|
```

Please check image:-

[image]

Please provide suggestions how can I get array column field in relationship

Comment: No, you cant with this DB structure

Comment: I've created a package for this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations#many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 2):

You should use a pivot table and a [many-to-many relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) to create this link correctly.

The new table would contain the `author_id` and the `local_id`. This way, a local row can have multiple authors and the relation can be defined in your database.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use for loop to fetch authors by using ID

Like You have an array author_id = [1, 3, 4]

so you need to loop it base on the count of the author_id array

```
for(i=0; i<= count(author_id); i++){
      //your condition based on the index of for loop
    select author from sometable where author_id[$i] = author
}
```

Comment: But this would create O(n+1) queries for every row.

Comment: If you want in one variable, then convert a variable into an array and put the result inside it